# Popup Window JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I have been using JavaScript popup windows, the windows were not saved as variables when I trigger them to open
Here is my code

```js
function trig(){var pwin = window.open('https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68612238/popup-window-javascript','popUpWindow','height=500,width=400,left=100,top=100,resizable=yes,scrollbars=yes,toolbar=yes,status=yes');document.querySelector('body').setAttribute('onclick', 'pwin.close()')};
```

```html
<div onclick="trig()">Click here</div>
```

[Here is an external link to try it](https://dmgnqz.mimo.run/App.html)
after clicking the Click Here button it should show a window, but I found out it doesn't save it as a variable. and then after the user presses the `<body>` element the window should close
Couldn't debug out any issues.

Comment: You need to declare the variable outside of your function. Also, if you're adding an onclick listener in your JS code, use the addEventListener method instead of setting an HTML attribute: `document.body.addEventListener('click', () => pwin.close());`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`pwin` is not declared globally. You should instead be calling the `close()` method inside the function.

```js
function trig() {
  var pwin = window.open('https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68612238/popup-window-javascript', 'popUpWindow', 'height=500,width=400,left=100,top=100,resizable=yes,scrollbars=yes,toolbar=yes,status=yes');
  document.querySelector('body').addEventListener('click', () => pwin.close());
};
```

---

It's closing immediately because when you click the 'Click here' button to open the window, the `click` event listener is added before the `click` event finishes firing, so it is immediately closed.

Instead, use `setTimeout` to add the event listener after, say, 50 milliseconds:

```js
function trig() {
  var pwin = window.open('https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68612238/popup-window-javascript', 'popUpWindow', 'height=500,width=400,left=100,top=100,resizable=yes,scrollbars=yes,toolbar=yes,status=yes');
  setTimeout(()=>{document.querySelector('body').addEventListener('click', () => pwin.close());}, 50);
};
```

Comment: Works but the window immediately closes, I need the `addEventListener()` to set AFTER  user clicks and the window opens.

Comment: @Vivaan It does not close immediately for me. Can't reproduce what you're talking about.

Comment: Check the demo, It does that over there. https://dmgnqz.mimo.run/App.html

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need to declare a global variable, instead of a local variable

Comment: I didn't spot that!

Comment: When I used it, it didn't really use local variable. but in the post I didn't see